Prove density of the set is 1/3
The following question is from G.de Barra's  Measure Theory and Integration
Prove that the set
$$ \{ x | x \neq 0, cos(\frac{1}{x})  > \frac{1}{2} \} $$
has density 1/3 at x = 0
I have tried to prove it in the following manner but not reaching the desired result
The density of a set E at a point x is defined to be
$$ \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\delta}m(E \cap I_{\delta}) $$
We Observe $$cos(t) > \frac{1}{2} $$ when $$t \in (2k\pi -\frac{\pi}{3}, 2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{3}) , k \in Z$$.
Then $$\frac{1}{x} \in (2k\pi -\frac{\pi}{3}, 2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{3}) \implies x\in (\frac{1}{2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{3}},\frac{1}{2k\pi -\frac{\pi}{3}}) $$
Let us fix $\delta > 0 .$ By Archimedes Property $$\exists  n_{0} \in N \ni\frac{1}{2n\pi -\frac{\pi}{3}} < \delta \,  \forall n \geq n_{0}$$
Then $$m(E \cap I_{\delta}) = 2\sum_{n \geq n_{0}}^{\infty}( \frac{1}{2k\pi -\frac{\pi}{3}} - \frac{1}{2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{3}}) = \frac{4\pi}{3}\sum_{n \geq n_{0}}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{(2k\pi)^2 - (\frac{\pi}{3})^2} = \frac{1}{3\pi}\sum_{n \geq n_{0}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2 - (\frac{1}{6})^2} $$
I do not know how to proceed forward.Thanks in advance

So far I believe that everything you did is correct. My idea on how to proceed is the following: Let's calculate $n_0$ explicitely:
$$\frac{1}{2n_0\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}} = \delta \Leftrightarrow n_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi \delta} + \frac 16.$$
Of course, we have to take the next integer number which is greater than or equal to this number; but in principle this is $n_0$.
Now the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 - (\frac 16)^2}$ is a decreasing and positive function on, say $[1, \infty)$. By the comparison test for series and integrals we know that
$$\int_{n_0}^\infty f(x)dx \le \sum_{k=n_0}^\infty f(n_0) \le f(k) + \int_{n_0}^\infty f(x) dx$$
(see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).
As we let $\delta \searrow 0$ the value $f(k)$ goes to zero, so we can ignore that term. It follows that the value of our series is the same as the value of the integral.
Evaluation of the integral leads to
$$\int_{n_0}^\infty f(x) dx = 3\left( \ln(6n_0+1)-\ln(6n_0-1)\right)$$
and plugging this in leads to the value
$$3 \ln\left( 1+ \frac{2\pi\delta}{3}\right).$$
Now to calculate the density, we still have to multiply by $\frac{1}{3\pi}$ (the constant in front of your sum) and by $\frac{1}{2\delta}$ by definition of the density. Hence we need to calculate
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi \delta} \ln\left( 1+ \frac{2\pi\delta}{3}\right)$$
At this point we use the Taylor expanson $\ln(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$ which yields
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi \delta} \ln\left( 1+ \frac{2\pi\delta}{3}\right) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi \delta} \left(\frac{2\pi \delta}{3} + O(\delta^2)\right) = \frac 13.$$

Thank you for answering and clearing my doubt Lukas!
